# ROS offline installation

Tags: ros, installation, offline

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I know that this question is already been asked but this threat didn't get me to the solution.
I'm trying to install the ROS-Base version on an ASCTEC Pelican. Unfortunately, is there no way to connect the Pelican to the internet. I can checkout the https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/ros/tags/ros-1.6.8 repository but how do I get the other Packages onto the machine. Would be great to get some help.

Thanks & Cheers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33469/ros-offline-installation/) by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 447 on 2012-05-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-05-07**:
Please save everyone's time by providing links to related questions you already consulted.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-05-07**:
Also please be a little bit more specific about what "other" pachages you want to install.  And what architecture/platform you are targeting.

**Comment by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on 2012-05-08**:
I would like to use this solution http://answers.ros.org/question/10201/ros-offline-install    which seemed pretty convenient at first but this is where the funny part starts... How do i get the apt-offline package on the non-network machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just go to http://packages.ubuntu.com/ and search for apt-offline. There, you can download the Debian package for your architecture.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2012-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on 2012-05-09**:
I did that and its running on the non-network machine (to be precise the asctec pelican). But how do I set up the softwaresource ( sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu maverick main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list' ) without an internet connection?